# Is it possible to measure the used bandwidth per udp/tcp port on linux?

Tags: linux, bash, bandwidth, bandwidth-measuring

I am wondering if there is a way to measure bandwidth by a tcp/udp port under Linux?

Means I search for a way to be able to tell, tcp/53 needs now 1MBit/s, tcp/80 needs now 4.5MBit/s. iperf is able to tell me this details, but my issue is I need it in shell/bash to extract the data for later use.

Answer (score 2):

i would recommend [darkstat](https://unix4lyfe.org/darkstat/), a description on how to is [available here](http://www.linuxfocus.org/English/September2004/article346.shtml)

Comment: Hello Corleone, thank you for darkstat, did not know about it before. I cannot find a option how to trace my specific ports to stdin or to a file for later parsing? Do you know how to handle it?

Comment: retrying: Corleone, can you help me on my query?

Comment: @cilap Nope!! Sry missed your comment, came to know the features of **darkstat**, and suggested  _post googling_

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, the best and easiest way to monitor bandwidth per port or bunch of ports under Linux, is to use `tc` to setup QoS.

You can use FireQoS - a high level tool for configuring QoS - and netdata for monitoring it in real-time.

Check this for more information: https://github.com/firehol/netdata/wiki/You-should-install-QoS-on-all-your-servers

Comment: This looks very interesting.  I already use `tc` a lot at home and at my VPS provider.  It will be interesting to see what kind of rules they effectively generate.

Comment: The link in this answer doesn't seem to lead to the intended content anymore. It looks like this content, or something similar, is now here: https://learn.netdata.cloud/docs/data-collection/networking-stack-and-network-interfaces/network-interface-qos